# Why does an object with a retain count of 0 respond to a message?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

With ARC turned off:

1. I create an instance of my custom class using `alloc`, so it has retain count of 1.
2. On the next line, I NSLog() the instance (I implemented a `description` method in my custom class).
3. On the next line, I release the object.
4. On the next line, I NSLog() the instance again, i.e. I send it a `description` message, and I see the same output in the console.  I expected some kind of error output.

Here is the relevant code:

AppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Greeter* host = [[Greeter alloc] initWithName:@"Maggie"];  //My custom class
    NSLog(@"Greeter %@", host);
    [host release];

    NSLog(@"Greeter %@", host); //Create error: send a `description` message to an object whose retain count is 0.


    return YES;
}

...
...
```

Greeter.m:

```
...

- (NSString*)description {
    return [
        [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"\n\tname: %@ \n\tCreated on %@", [self name], [self today]]
        autorelease
    ];
}
```

--output in Console:--

```
2015-04-26 21:18:58.914 Flashlight[2380:62826] Greeter 
    name: Maggie 
    Created on 2015-04-27 03:18:58 +0000
2015-04-26 21:18:58.915 Flashlight[2380:62826] Greeter 
    name: Maggie 
    Created on 2015-04-27 03:18:58 +0000
```

Similar code `in cocoa`, causes weird stuff to happen, and Xcode flags the second NSLog() with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

**Response to comments:**

I decided to start a new app to try some things, and here is what I discovered:

1. In Xcode 6.2, even though there is no error in the console, i.e. both NSLog()'s print the same thing, `Product>Analyze` will point out the line with the error saying: `Reference-counted object is used after it is released`.  And if I click on that message, Xcode shows a nice graphical explanation of how that happened in the code.
2. If I `edit the scheme` to enable Zombie objects, then instead of the second NSLog() message, I get an error message:

> Flashlight3[606:11093] *** -[Greeter respondsToSelector:]: message
>   sent to deallocated instance 0x7fb5e1caa8c0

After poking around in Xcode for much too long, I figured out how to `edit the scheme`.  To the right of the Run and Stop buttons, there is a *jump bar* showing: `ProjectName>Platform`, which in my case is `Flashlight>iPhone6`.  I clicked on Flashlight, and a drop down list displayed `Edit scheme`.  I clicked on `Edit scheme`, then under `Run/Debug`, there is a checkbox for `Enable Zombie Objects`, which I checked.

> Did you compile with debug symbols?

I guess not.  I read some Apple docs to figure out how to do that: I clicked on the top line in the Project Navigator, chose Build Settings, then I scrolled down to Build Options, then I selected `Build Variants`, then I clicked the arrow to reveal Debug and Release.  To the right of `Debug`, I clicked on `normal`, and I typed in `debug`.

I'm not sure what that does.  I see no difference after doing that.

> Do you find your code in the stack trace?

In the Stack Trace area:

1. Product>Profile
2. Scroll down the window and choose Zombies.
3. Then click the red Record button.
4. A Zombie Messaged popup will appear.
5. Inside the popup, click the arrow with the gray circle around it.
6. In the bottom pane, click on the Zombie line.
7. In the bottom right pane, at the top of pane, select the icon on the far right.

...there are a bunch of names in a list preceded by an icon:

[image]

Some of the icons are black.  If I click on enough of the black icons, I eventually jump to my code.  Doing that is problematic, though, because when I click on one of the black icons, it is hard to get back to the Stack Trace list to try another black icon. *Edit:* Okay, I found a way to get around that problem: when I click on one of the icons in the Stack Trace pane, it takes me to some code where one of the lines will have a red arrow pointing at it.  If I click on the red arrow, it will show me a popup containing the Stack Trace list, and then I can click on one of the other black icons.

Comment: What does logging the object's `retainCount` show?

Comment: @rebello95, Well, calling release on the object a second time causes an error.  I'll try logging the retain count.

Comment: @rebello95, The retain count is still 1 on the line after `[host release]`.  Why is that?

Comment: Per Apple - *never* rely on the result of a call to `retainCount`.

Comment: You might want to implement the `dealloc` method in your `Greeter` class to log a message so you can see when it is called.

Comment: @rmaddy, Okay, I'll implement dealloc.

Comment: @rmaddy, I posted the output in the console in my question.  When I implement dealloc, the output from the NSLog() in dealloc comes between the two descriptions.

Comment: And that's expected since the call to `release` should lead to the object being deallocated.

Comment: @rmaddy, Yes.  What I didn't expect is to be able to send any messages to  an object whose retain count is 0.

Comment: My answer explains why you see what you see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because an object's retain count goes to 0 and its `dealloc` method is called, doesn't mean the memory used by the object is instantly turned to garbage. The deallocated object could possibly sit in memory, intact, for a while before the memory space is reused for something else.

That seems to be the case here. The call to log `host` after it's been deallocated finds that the memory for the deallocated object is still intact so accessing its data works.

But it seems in your test on a Mac results in the memory being handled differently causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

rmaddy's answer is completely correct. But likely you want to know, how to get an error message in such a case.

There are two options:

- Run the static analyzer. It can detect some of these errors.
- Enable the zombie option in the scheme. This will keep the instance objects alive and report an error message, if they are used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Should I run `Product>Analyze` and `Product>Profile>(scroll down the window)Zombies` (Then hit the red Record button, then in the popup message click the arrow with a circle around it.) as a matter of course when doing IOS programming?  Also, I can't figure out how to jump from Instruments/Zombies to the code where the problem is (Xcode 6.2).   The apple docs say:...

Comment: *4. When a Zombie Messaged dialog appears, click the focus button to the right of the message text in the dialog. 5. Open the Extended Detail inspector in the sidebar pane, and double-click the Zombie entry in the Event Type column of the object history table. 6. Double-click the responsible caller in the Stack Trace section of the Extended Detail inspector to display the responsible code.*---In step 5, double clicking doesn't seem to do anything; and for step 6 I am not sure how to identify the responsible caller--clicking random things just takes me into what looks like assembly code.

Comment: This are two options. The first one is reached by Product|Analyze. Correct. For the second one you can turn on the Zombie option in the scheme "run(debug)" as mentioned. It is not wrong to use the profiler, too. Did you compile with debug symbols? Do you find your code in the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My response to your comment was too long, so I added my response to the bottom of my question.